# How to go about creating Windows like GUI using C

Tags: c, user-interface, ubuntu

I am working on ubuntu, and till date I've worked with C only and written console applications only. But now I want to provide a windows like GUI for my program.

I want to do something as follows.

I want to have a window, where each pixel signifies a cell in 2D array with a default value. Now whenever I draw something on the window with my cursor, the corresponding cell in my matrix gets filled with the value. Now, I have no experience in such programming and would greatly appreciate the guidance for the same.

Also, since this is just the first part of my complete process, and the matrix will serve as the input to the rest of my program, I am looking for some lucid material that can really help me achieve it quickly, that would be great.

Edit: I am ready to abandon C for the purpose, if it really is necessary. 
Also, if there's already some linux based tool available that can help me , I am all for it. But still I'd like to know, how to go about building one tool with minimal functionalities(as described above) on my own. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the tutorials for libGTK.

Comment: There are multiple possible libraries for this. Other than on windows you may have different WindowManagers (and their libraries) on Linux. Try to get an overview which one might fit your purpose and skills most and give it a try. But keep in mind, that you may have to install a lot of libraries, if you choose something that is not already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with GTK.

A good starting Point is the DrawingArea Tutorial:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.24/c2422.html

To develop in GTK, you need to install libgtk 
`apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

Here is a simple C Example, where i store Points in an Array:
https://gist.github.com/pce/5134167

Comment: I see that in the `https://gist.github.com/pce/5134167` you have written to use `gcc -Wall -g 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0' drawarea.c -o drawarea` but when I do so, it gives me all sorts of warnings and errors, saying undefined references, but when I do `gcc drawarea.c -o drawarea 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0'` , it works fine.